# Handle JSON response data and String response data respectively in callback

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

My backend can either return JSON or plain string data in response.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
    if error == nil {
       // Handle response data, but it could be JSON & it could also be String data, how to check and distinguish & handle respectively?
       if let data = data {
                // it fails here if the data is String
                if let jsonDataDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? JSONDataDict {

                } else {
          }

    }
}
```

In the response callback, how to check wither the response `data` is `JSON` format or `String` , how to handle respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `String` initialiser passing data an UTf8 as string encoding

```
if let data = data {
                // it fails here if the data is String
                if let jsonDataDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? JSONDataDict {

                } else {
                if let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
                      debugPrint(dataString)
                }
          }

    }
```

Comment: can I change to `else if let dataString=...`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let jsonDataDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? JSONDataDict

 if let strJSON = jsonDataDict as? [String:String] //you can cast in string as
 {
    if strJSON?.isEmpty == false {
        //It is empty
    } 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let data = data {
        if data is Data {
            //do operation with Data
            if let jsonDataDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? JSONDataDict {
            }
        }
        else if data is String {
            //do operation with string
        }
    }
```

[AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

> Use the type check operator (is) to check whether an instance is of a
>   certain subclass type. The type check operator returns true if the
>   instance is of that subclass type and false if it is not.

Comment: Thanks, if I follow the same data type checking style, how can I check whether the JSON data contains a list of object or one object?

Comment: As you using `jsonDataDict` which gives you dictionary count